# Instantiate doesn't work in unity with navmesh

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I'm having some problems on instantiating an enemy in unity, it gives me always this error *setDestination" can only be called on an active agent that has been placed on a NavMesh.*, and then it places a 2d model somewhere in my map

```
    public GameObject enemy;
    public Transform spawn;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        spawnNew();
    }
    void spawnNew() {

        Instantiate(enemy, spawn.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        
    }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code that correlates to your error. Please provide a better minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

After you have spawned an enemy, call the NavMeshAgent.Warp() function to position the agent on the desired position, which of course must be inside the navmesh.